# Is this due to Code conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script installed on my website:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js' type='text/javascript'>
{lang: &#39;en-US&#39;}
</script>
```

When I try to add another element with following script, it refuses to show up any responce -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://project.dimpost.com/flexslider-carousel/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://project.dimpost.com/flexslider-carousel/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

What could be the issue and how to resolve that?

Comment: Check your browser console for errors. Also, verify that you are calling the flexslider in a proper way.

Comment: If it's not a copy/paste mistake in your first code excerpt, you're importing the same script twice. Have you tried removing one import and trying again?

Comment: Surprisingly, no errors in console and no duplication issue as well. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I must admit, there are errors. See below _ Rakesh Yadav.

Answer (score 2):

You can do without the window.load event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://project.dimpost.com/flexslider-carousel/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://project.dimpost.com/flexslider-carousel/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, it is the same

Answer (score 0):

remove the below script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://project.dimpost.com/flexslider-carousel/jquery.js"></script>
```

you have already loaded the jquery using below line

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check on browser console, you should see some error or more information on error.

Comment: It shows two errors: 1.TypeError: $ is not a function  2.Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead

Comment: I have alresdy modified the code using: $.noConflict(); jQuery(document).ready(function($) Still the issue persists.